# Import csv file with both tab and quotes as separators into R

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset in csv with separators as displayed below.

```
NO_CAND";"DS_CARGO";"CD_CARGO";"NR_CAND";"SG_UE";"NR_CNPJ";"NR_CNPJ_1";
CLODOALDO JOSÉ DE RAMOS";"Deputado Estadual";"7";"22111";"PB";"08126218000107";"Encargos financeiros e taxas bancárias";
```

I am using the function read.csv2 with options

```
mydataframe <- read.csv2("filename.csv",header = T, sep=";", quote="\\'", dec=",",
stringsAsFactors=F,  check.names = F, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

The code reads in the data, but with all the quotes.

I have tried to delete the quotes using

```
mydataframe[,] <- apply(mydataframe[,], c(1,2), function(x) { 
gsub("\\'", "", x)
})
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I could import the data getting rid of these quotes?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is that supposed to be 1 line of input, or 4?

Comment: I'm sorry about my mistakes. I have edited the question. @HongOoi, now I have 2 lines of input, the header and a row of data with 7 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the quotes, use `lapply` and `gsub` as follows.

```
mydataframe[] <- lapply(mydataframe, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x))
```

`lapply` iterates over all columns of the data frame and returns a list; by having `mydataframe[]` on the LHS of the assignment, you assign the results back into the data frame without losing its attributes (dimensions, names, etc). Also, you don't have any single quotes `'` in your data, so searching for them won't achieve anything.

Comment: mydataframe[] <- lapply(mydataframe, function(x) {gsub("\"", "", x)})